# nusoap webservices return nothing

Tags: php, web-services, nusoap

I try to learn web services with PHP so download nusoap lib and find a tutorial
created the files but there is no result

```
 <?php

    require_once('lib/nusoap.php');

    $testa = array('name" => "TEST');

    $addw = new nusoap_client('http://127.0.0.1/Web%20services/server.php?wsdl',true);
    $res = $addw -> call('getmessage',$testa);
    echo $res;
    ?>

this is client.php

    <?php
require_once("lib/nusoap.php");
$auth = new nusoap_server();
$auth->configureWSDL("authenticate","urn:service1");
function getmessage($message){
    return "welcome ". $message;
}

$auth->register(
                "getmessage"
                ,array("name"=>"xsd:string")
                ,array("sum"=>"xsd:string")
                );

$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';
$auth->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
?>
```

and this is the server one
using wamp and test with another sample but no fortune